# Calculating B and |V| in naive bayes text classification

Tags: classification, multinomial

I found a link about multinomial naive bayes classifier

[multinomial naive bayes link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/naive-bayes-text-classification-1.html#laplace)

How we could calculate the `B'` or `|V|`?

The page said that it is the number of terms in the vocabulary. In its example, how we could get `6` for `B`? Is it the counting of all term?

> "chinese", "beijing", "shanghai", "meacao", "tokyo", "japan"

One more question, what if new term appear in testing document? example, in doc 6 appears "bangkok" or any new word that never appear before. how to count the probability of new term ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. It's the total number of words in the vocabulary, since there can be only one entry for a term in the vocabulary.

Comment: One more question, what if new term appear in testing document?
example, in doc 6 appears "bangkok" or any new word that never appear before. how to count the probability of new term ?
thank you passion :)